# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘?’ token

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So I am getting this error even though the code I am compiling has no '?' at all.
I am using gcc as my compiler & linker. Any tips on why this is happening?

Also, when I remove the 'l' from the function name the error goes away. Im confused.

Code snippet where the error is showing up:

```
unsigned long htonl(unsigned long ll) //Says error is on this line
{
    UDWord x;
    UDWord y;

    x.ul = ll;
    y.uc[0] = x.uc[3];
    y.uc[1] = x.uc[2];
    y.uc[2] = x.uc[1];
    y.uc[3] = x.uc[0];
    return y.ul;
}
```

Comment: Looks like htonl is a networking command, or a predefined function: http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl

Comment: Enclose the function name in parentheses: `unsigned long (htonl)(unsigned long ll)`.  This avoids expansion of `htonl` if it is defined as a function-like macro.  But then you need to think about why you are redefining a function already provided by the implementation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer your own version of `htonl` over the built-in version?

Comment: This code was given to me for a summer project. Im guessing my grad student had reasons that I dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure a routine is actually a `function`, not a `macro` (some of the standard library routines are, e.g, `putchar` usually is), you can use `#undef` like this:

```
#undef htonl
unsigned long htonl(unsigned long ll) 
{
    UDWord x;
    UDWord y;

    x.ul = ll;
    y.uc[0] = x.uc[3];
    y.uc[1] = x.uc[2];
    y.uc[2] = x.uc[1];
    y.uc[3] = x.uc[0];
    return y.ul;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

htonl is sometimes defined as a macro in the standard include files for gcc.  Use a different name.